# CSS in child theme not overriding the parent theme

Tags: theme-development, themes, css, child-theme

I am trying to make a child theme for a premium template.

My css isn't overriding the parent though. I'm trying to figure out what's going on. Other than important the parent theme's css, is there anything else I need to import into the child theme folder? Right now there is just style.css.

The site is http://wpdallas.com/test/

Comment: I just noticed you edited my question. I can't seem to see what you edited (or what I entered in incorrectly.) :)

Comment: @Brady edited the title (removed 'Child Theme question'), and layout of the question.

Comment: @RickSmith - I changed the title to be more descriptive of your issue. You can see amendments here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/43122/revisions

Comment: Close-voted as **too localized**. This is most likely an issue with your commercial Theme's handling of stylesheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem in the theme itself, this has been corrected since this question was posted. The parent theme was not properly coded to work with a child theme.

Answer (score 0):

It's throwing some errors for the some of the style sheets... are you sure you've got them in the right theme folder? because you seem to be calling from two separate themes:

Standard-Child-Theme-1 & Standard.

If they are in the same folder, I'd personally use  to  make life easier.

Comment: Hmmm. I made a change in one of the parent themes that seemed to fix my issue, but I do see there are some errors that are showing up,..some 404's on some of the style sheets its trying to pull in.  The first theme is the child theme, the 2nd is the parent. Here is my style sheet for the child theme, how's it look? http://wpdallas.com/test/wp-content/themes/Standard-Child-Theme-1/style.css

Comment: Could you try in this @import url("../Standard/standard_framework/css/standard_framework.css");

The other thing, I've noticed in your child theme css - you're styling elements that I can't seem to find on your site.

Comment: Ok, I've added that import line...also what elements am I styling that you can find in the theme? (Thanks for your help by the way.)

Comment: ignore my comment about the elements... found them.

Comment: Ok. You had me worried there for a bit. :) Does it look like adding that line of code fixed my issues?

Comment: Well the child theme is loading fine - however the frameworks.css and framework.js is not loading - the element itself - when inspecting the element ie #social #facebook it shows the styling... but it's not loading the background image. I'm a bit perplexed as to why it's not showing... I'll have a look into it. The only thing difference is, it's cross browser... try putting the sprite image on a local place ie wpdallas.com

Comment: Ok got it - you're styling the div background of the #facebook and not the <a> element. Style the <a> element's background instead...it'll show up then.

Comment: what is the <a> element? Sorry, you lost me with that one. :)

Comment: I'm confused because on my css file for the child theme I don't see where I'm styling that at all.

Comment: It seems to be working now. I'm not sure what is going on, I just added `div.social_icon img {background: none;} and it seems to work now. How does it look? Can you tell if it was done correctly?