# Child Style.css not overriding parent theme style located in assets/css/main.css

Tags: themes, child-theme, css

I know this question has been asked before, and I've already referenced the following questions here:

[Child Theme Not Overriding Parent Theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/233184/child-theme-not-overriding-parent-theme)

[some things in child theme css not overriding parent](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92157/some-things-in-child-theme-css-not-overriding-parent)

[CSS in child theme not overriding the parent theme [closed]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43122/css-in-child-theme-not-overriding-the-parent-theme)

[Function in Child Theme not overriding Parent Theme function [duplicate]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157865/function-in-child-theme-not-overriding-parent-theme-function)

None of these address my particular issue.

The issue I am having is that the stylesheet for my parent theme isn't located in the traditional `themedirectory/style.css`. They did all the styling in `themedirectory/assets/css/main.css`. So I tried to create the child theme and added the following code to my `functions.php` file:

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'maya-reloaded-style';
        wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/css/main.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
            array( $parent_style ),
            wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
        );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
    ?>
```

I updated the directory of the parent theme to the location of the current parent theme, but I still have an issue of my new stylesheet not overwriting the parent's child theme. It seems like the parent's stylesheet is being loaded after the child style sheet. When I inspect the element with Firefox it shows that the parent stylesheet is overwriting the child stylesheet.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this so the child stylesheet is loaded after the parent stylesheet?

**UPDATE**

Here is the *PARENT* (main.css) file:

```
/*
Theme Name: Maya Reloaded
Description: Onepage, Multipage and Mutipurpose WP Theme
Theme URI: http://themeforest.net/user/unCommons/portfolio
Author: unCommons Team
Author URI: http://www.uncommons.pro
Version: 1.1
License: GNU General Public License version 3.0
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
Tags: one-column, two-columns, right-sidebar, fluid-layout, custom-menu, editor-style, featured-images, post-formats, translation-ready
*/


/* Main Style -> assets/css/main.css */
```

Here is the *CHILD* (style.css) file:

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Maya Reloaded - Child
 Theme URI:    http:www.girlpowerhour.com/Maya-child
 Description:  Child theme for the Maya Reloaded theme
 Author:       Me
 Author URI:   http:www.virgsolutions.com
 Template:     maya-reloaded
 Version:      2.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready, pink
 Text Domain:  maya-reloaded-child
*/

body{
    font-size:18px;
}

.larger-font{
    font-size:18px;
}

.about-header{
    font-size:24px;
}

/* Header */
.un-header-menu-white .main-menu  li  a{
    color:#EF1066;
}
```

Comment: Could you please share us the code in their `style.css`? The theme header should be there at least.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam I updated my question.

Comment: #blaine did you check that the CHILD-THEME template name is correct

Comment: @Mukiikumar what do you mean? Can you be more specific?

Comment: If you are referring to the template being the correct directory of the parent theme, then yes, that is correct.

Comment: May be a not a great idea but try to switch to default theme and then switch back to your child theme again and then refresh page with `ctrl + f5`. And also check if there is an error in console.

Comment: One more thing, in your function (`my_theme_enqueue_styles`) the line in which you are calling parent theme's main.css, on this line you have forgot to add slash(`/`) after `get_template_directory_uri()`. Means the path that you have mentioned `assets/css/...` must be start with slash like you did in the line in which you are calling child theme's style.css.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following. In your add_action( ) call add the priority and tell if it solves the issue.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles', 99 );
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because the rules in their stylesheet have higher Specificity.  add `!important` after one of your css rules and see if it works then.

You shouln't use `!important` unless you have to but it will tell us if it is the problem.

If it is, have a read of this article: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/